# Change of IP address

Tags: ip-address

How do I change an IP DNS address to an automatic IP address?

Comment: This question makes no sense

Comment: I agree with Sparr, this question needs clarification. Are you talking about static vs. DHCP, updating DNS entries on a server, or using DHCP to assign which DNS servers to use?

Answer (score 7):

IIRC, automatic IP addresses have been made illegal. You can, however, still use semi-automatic IP addresses.

Comment: Nice :)       .

Comment: haha, I just hope that Edgar doesn't think that this is a real answer, and then ask "Why are automatic IP addresses illegal?"

Comment: Really, though. That question will get him further along that the one he originally posed. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It depends heavily on what OS you're running. It also requires that you get your IP address via DHCP.

In Linux (Red Hat), you'd edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-$INTERFACE`. In Windows, you'd go to Network Connections->"INTERFACE"->Internet Protocol->Properties.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows XP if your asking how to change from a static IP to DHCP

Click "Start" --> Click "Run" --> Type "control netconnections"

Right click on the interface you want to configure --> Select "Properties"

In the box for "This connection uses the following items:" select "Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) --> Click "Properties"

Change the setting under the "General" tab to "Obtain an IP address automatically" --> Repeat for DNS server if needed.